# list indices must be integers, not numpy.float64

Tags: python

When i try to test my datasets which is in the form of .pkl, i am getting this kind of error. The following is the portion of code which arises this particular error :

```
f = open("TP_index_blstm.pkl",'wb')
    pickle.dump(result[1], f)
    f.close()
    #print(type(result[1]))
    f_TP = open("./result_analyze/BGRU/TP_filenames.txt","ab+")
    for i in range(len(str(result[1]))):
       TP_index = result[i]
       f_TP.write(str(filenames[TP_index])+'\n')
```

I can't understand why this error occurs, i am new to this kind of error, please suggest me a solution for this IndexError. The type of result[1] is  .The errors occurs is shown as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bgru.py", line 240, in <module>
    main(traindataSetPath, testdataSetPath, realtestdataSetPath, weightPath, resultPath, batchSize, maxLen, vectorDim, layers, dropout)
  File "bgru.py", line 154, in main
    f_TP.write((filenames[TP_index])+'\n')
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not numpy.float64
```

Comment: " The type of result[1] is ." - is **what?**

Comment: You probably want `"a"`, not `"ab+"`, for the mode. It shouldn't be opened in binary mode if you are writing `str` values, and you aren't trying to read from the file at all, so `+` isn't necessary.

Comment: @chepner when i remove + from it, same error is occuring...

Comment: That wasn't a solution to the problem, just an unrelated suggestion.

Comment: @Błotosmętek type of result[1] is <type 'numpy.float64'>

Comment: @chepner okay i just tried with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `print(TP_index, type(TP_index))` before the `f_TP.write` line, and you'll probably figure out the problem.

`TP_index` is a `numpy.float64` according to the error, so you can't use it as an array index.

Comment: yes type of TP_index is <type 'numpy.float64'>. so how could i remove this error?? I tried to find a solution for this, but i am failing

Comment: @angel `filenames` is a list. Lists are indexed by integers, i.e. you can call `filenames[i]` where `i` is an integer, and that should give the `i`th element of the list. In your case you are calling `filenames[TP_index]` where `TP_index` is not an integer, so you have an error. Imagine `TP_index = 1.234`, the 1.234th element of a list has no meaning, hence the TypeError.

Comment: It is hard to help more without knowing what your input file is, and what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: my input files are c or c++ programs that are vulnerable or not, now my input files are in the form of .pkl, i am trying to check whether there are vulnerabilites or not in my files, python program currently i am running is build  bgru model, train the dataset and test it, and to print the accuracy, etc..

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what .pkl files or bgru are. It would be easier if you could provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The "filenames" is a list, so the index must be integers.

```
my_list = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] 
# index of my_list is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
print('First element :', my_list[0])
output : 'a'
```

In your case, I think it better to use the dictionary.

```
my_dict = {0.555:my_list}
print(my_dict[0.555])
output : ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
```